# Dividing a table cell into two parts

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I divide a table cell into two parts?

Answer (score 1):

A table cell is bydefault divided in three sections, the image on the left, the text labels in the center and the accessory view on the right.
If u want more divisions or customize them, you have to customize the table cell by inheriting the UITableViewCell.

Comment: So, if you are not using any of the standard accesoryTypes, you can use the accessoryView as your second view.  (Your first view would be the rest of the cell, the other two sections.)

Comment: yes you can do that, but it wont be a good or not the best solution. its better you go for customization.

Answer (score 0):

You can add simply 2 SubViews in to the cell and nest whatever you want inside.

Comment: And if you want to seperate them obtically you add an additional ImageView which inherits an seperator

Comment: Iam asking cell have two parts one part contain lable and another part contain image.Between these two iwant place the line.That is i want two columns within one row only.Remaining columns normal

Answer (score 0):

As told by shani,
  Create two subview with its frame and add them on the cell.
Here I will show sample structure,

```
UITableViewCell *cell  = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
UILabel *label1=//create a label1 with frame
UILabel *label2=//create a label2 with frame
[cell.contentView  addSubview:label1];
[cell.contentView  addSubview:label2];
```

Comment: This is a good option, but subviews should be added to cell.contentView, rather than directly to the cell.